# post photo with description Facebook sdk 3

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

how to post photo with description with new facebook sdk ?

I tried with :

```
         Request photoRequest = Request.newUploadPhotoRequest(Session.getActiveSession(),mBitmap , new Callback() {

            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        Bundle params = photoRequest.getParameters();
        params.putString("message", "description  goes here");
        photoRequest.executeAsync();
```

But I'm not see any function with bundle as params, how can i solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Request class has a setParameters(Bundle) method.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/Request#setParameters(Bundle)

Answer (score 0):

Put

`params.putString("name", "description  goes here");`